# Form SOAP request using Eclipse Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, web, client

I need to write a Java client to call a SOAP call in a webservice.
I have an xml file defining the request.
I have a .svc file.
My wsdl URI is something like this: wsdlLocation="http://xx.com/E/wcf/test.svc"

I have started a new Eclipse WTP WEb Services Client and am getting an error when specifying 
http://xx.com/E/wcf/test.svc?wsdl in the Service definition file.
I get this error: WAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL:  javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:import): faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unable to resolve imported document at 'http:// ... etc.

For the moment I want to ignore that :) because I'm not sure I understand all this fully.

If it was successful, is there something that would allow me to point at the xml file and generate the SOAP calls, to create the request and check or responses. Something to write the xml elements etc.?
I have looked at so many tutorials at this stage and so many questions and answers that I am getting lost.

There seems to be some many ways to do things using the eclipse plug ins which ends up confusing me in the end. I have Eclipse Juno and I have the m2eclipse WTP plugin.

Can anyone point me to a definitive sample where I can create an instance of my service using this wsdl, form a SOAP request and check for a response?
I have a html page that I need to send and need to encode it within the soap request in a string.

Thank you.